# Definition of a tangent vector as a differential operator via Tangent Map?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-operators, tangent-spaces

Am I correct with the following reasoning:
$\phantom{f}$

We defined tangent vectors on a manifold $M$ at point $p$ as equivalence classes of paths $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$. Two paths $\gamma_{1/2}$ are identified with as same tangent vectors if for all local coordinates x: $(x \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (x \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$.
I think the following should be the definition for a vector $X$ as a differential operator (in coordinate independent form):
$$ X(f) := Tf(X) $$
Why?:

Let $M,N$ be two n-dim manifolds, $f:M \rightarrow N$. Then by our definition:
$$ Tf(X) = [f\circ \gamma] $$
After choosing local coordinates $(U,x)$ on $M$ and $(V,y)$ on $N$, we define the coordinate function **Edit (in bold):** $f_C:=\mathbf{y} \circ f \circ x^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and coordinate vector $X_C = (x\circ \gamma)'(0) = \begin{pmatrix} X^1 \\ ... \\ X^n \end{pmatrix}$ and $p_C = x\circ p$. Then:
$$ Tf_C(X) = (f_C \circ (x \circ \gamma) )'(0) = Df_C((x \circ \gamma)(0)) (x \circ \gamma)'(0) = Df_C(p_C)(X_C) $$
$$= \underbrace{(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f_C(p_C) , ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f_C(p_C))}_{\text{Jacobi-Matrix}} \begin{pmatrix} X^1 \\ ... \\ X^n \end{pmatrix} = X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f_C(p_C)$$
Where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f_C(p_C)$ lives in $y$-Coordinates of $N$.

That's exactly the formula that our professor introduced for $X(f)$ when he said we regard $X$ as a differential operator:
$$ X(f) = X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f $$
Only that no distinction between the actual tangent vector/function and the respective coordinate forms is made.

Is the above reasoning correct? Is that a valid definition?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f_C:=y\circ f \circ x^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Yes, you're right it should. What is wrong with the above reasoning then?

Comment: That is, why doesn't it hold for the coordinate represntation of an arbitrary $f: M \rightarrow N$?

Comment: Scalar functions on manifold are very important and nice, for them we have this intuitive "how much f changes in X direction" directional derivative $X(f)$. Generally though the more intuitive view is that a map derivative pushes tangent vectors between manifolds $df(X)=Y$, or in coordinates you have the Jacobian matrix-vector product $\frac{\partial(y)}{\partial(x)}X=Y$

Comment: Yes, and is this map derivative $df(X)$ for a general f the same as $X(f)$ ?

Comment: For a general map $f$ notation $X(f)$ is not used. Mapping to $\mathbb R$ is privileged because $\mathbb R$ coincides with its tangent space, it's ordered, and so on. So for the $\mathbb R$-valued maps we have directional derivative, with a tangent vector acting on such functions. Let's not continue this discussion here or it will be moved away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the map derivative/"Tangent Map"/exterior derivative of a function we have the formula expressing it as a directional derivative: $df(X)=X(f)$, where $X$ is an arbitrary tangent vector.

$df$ is linear so is the $X$ as an operator. So in a coordinate chart, with coordinate curves, and the corresponding basis of the tangent space we have
$$df(X)=X(f)=\left(X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) f=X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$$

Where in the last equality there's some implicit identification  reusing the same symbol $f$ for $f(x^1,\dots, x^n)=f\circ p(x^1,\dots, x^n)$, and the directional derivative is given by the usual partial derivative, it can be shown by properly considering the coordinate curves (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4307713/73934))

Comment: So that's true for a general $f:M \rightarrow N$? or rather for the same map in local coordinates $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ ?

Comment: It's true for a smooth function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$